# Customizing popup menu style

Tags: android, android-styles, popupmenu, material-components, material-components-android

I'm currently using this style for my popup menu:

```
<style name="mainActivityTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

How ever it causes popup menus to have extra space on the top and bottom:

[image]

How do I make it so there is no extra space? Is there a certain style so that it wraps its contents?

**Edit: I forgot to mention I inflate the view programmatically so that may be an issue**

```
private void inflateMoreMenu(View view){
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.popup_menu_report:
                        //Inflate a layout

                        break;
                    case R.id.popup_menu_block:
                        //Inflate a layout

                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
        MenuPopupHelper menuHelper = new MenuPopupHelper(mContext, (MenuBuilder) popupMenu.getMenu(), view);
        menuHelper.setForceShowIcon(true);
        menuHelper.show();
    }
```

XML for popup_menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/popup_menu_report"
        android:title="Report"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_messages_report"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/popup_menu_block"
        android:title="Block"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_alertdialog_block"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the OverflowMenu you can define in your app theme the `actionOverflowMenuStyle` attribute.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/popupOverflowMenu</item>
</style>
```

With:

```
  <style name="popupOverflowMenu" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/my_mtrl_popupmenu_background</item>   
  </style>
```

The `drawable/my_mtrl_popupmenu_background.xml` file:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="?attr/colorSurface"/>

  <corners
      android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
      android:topRightRadius="4dp"/>

</shape>
```

It the original file there is the `padding`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="?attr/colorSurface"/>

  <corners
    ..../>

  <padding
      android:bottom="8dp"
      android:top="8dp"/>

</shape>
```

[image]

For a popup you can use:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
   <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="popupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/my_mtrl_popupmenu_background</item>   
</style>
```

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't seem to quite work for me unless I change my main activity's theme to: <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/popup</item> but this then removes my popup menu anchor. I forgot to mention I inflate the menu programmatically!

Comment: @davids. Sorry my bad. I was thinking only for a overflowmenu. I've just added the style for a simple popup.

Comment: No problem! Your method for the popup works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Worked only with the `android` prefix for the popup menu: `android:popupMenuStyle` in the theme.